# How to say "times left until something"

Tags: phrase-request

Ho can I say there is some time until an event? Suppose there is a puzzle whose answer is an image, which should I say:

> five seconds to show the image
>
> five seconds are left to show the image
>
> five seconds are left until showing the image
>
> five seconds are left until the image to be shown

Comment: More context, please. Would this sentence be used in a computer program, or in speech?

Comment: You can use *five seconds to go.*

Comment: There are **many** valid ways to say this; here is one I like: _Five seconds until the image will be shown_.

Comment: @CopperKettle Computer program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Five seconds to show the image

This means that **you** have five seconds to show the image. The problem here is that the implication is that the user is going to be the one showing the image.

> Five seconds are left to show the image

Same problem here. This means that the user has 5 seconds left to show the image.

> Five seconds are left until showing the image

This doesn't have the same problem as before, but I still don't like this one. It sounds awkward. You could make it sound better by saying "until the showing of the image," but that is too verbose anyway.

> five seconds are left until the image to be shown

This is missing a verb. It should be

> Five seconds are left until the image is to be shown

However, this is too verbose in my opinion.

For something like counting down time until a puzzle ends, I find this to be common enough and not be too verbose:

> Five seconds remaining until image is shown

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like in this context, a complete sentence is not required. A fragment will suffice, and the shorter the better, since the puzzle-solver will not want to waste time reading a long message. I'd shorten Alex K's answer to:

> 5 seconds remaining

or

> Time left: 5 seconds

I'm deliberately using a numeral rather than text. This is more of a user interface (UI) issue than a question of grammar. Brevity and clarity are paramount.

Comment: I agree - if this is for an app, this would be the way to display a counter somewhere.

Comment: +1 for 'time left'. That's what exactly I see (and of course I believe the best way to say that) in McDonald's here in India. They play such interesting puzzles all time on TVs kept in the restaurants.

Answer (score 1):

In all three examples, it **sounds** like you are addressing the projectionist instead of the person viewing

> 1) five seconds **to show** the image
>   2) five seconds are left **to show** the image
>   3) five seconds are left **until showing** the image

better phrasing might be :

> 1) five seconds to **see** the image
>   2) five seconds left to **see** the image
>   3) five seconds left until **the image is gone**

shorter versions might be :

> five seconds **left**
>   five seconds **to go**
>   **ends in** five seconds
>   **displays/disappears** in five seconds *(specifically since something is being shown)*

Especially for **showing** something:

> Five seconds until **showtime!**

Comment: I think that the answer to the puzzle is an image, and he is counting down the time until the answer is revealed.

Comment: That was my original thought also, then after repeating it to myself a few times, I realised it is ambiguous and could be either, depends on context and intonation